# Blazor Navigation Manager Go Back?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side

While using blazor, I want to be able to "go back" to a page I was before.

I found this [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/12838) and looks like it's a dead end?

This feature is something so basic, that I can't believe it doesn't exits.

Is there any walk around to make this "go back" functionality ?

Please notice that I cannot use `window.goBack` or `history.goBack` because my app doesn't create any history, and also shouldn't create any history.

The only way to "create" a history is to use the `forceLoad` option of `Navigation.NavigateTo` but if I do, it will try to load my entire app again, which is slow and I don't want to.

Answer (score 33):

How about using JavaScript?

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

// Go back in browser using Javascript on a Razor Page 
private async Task GoBack()
{
    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("history.back");
}
```

Or use a standard link if there's no need to draw a button and handle an event:

```
<a onclick="history.back();">Return</a>
```

Comment: Does `NavigationManager.Uri` reflect this change?

Comment: Yes, this is what I guess. (The questioner said, that he hasn't a history. Therfore it isn't a solution for him, I guess)

Comment: Bad @Community bot! This is a perfectly acceptable answer and, IMHO the simplest and most elegant and addresses the question asked directly. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Great answer ! I think this answer must be mark accepted answer

Comment: This works really well.

Answer (score 27):

What you need is a page history state manager:

For the following example I'm using Blazor Wasm but you can use this example in Blazor Server as well.

In the client app I've added this class:
PageHistoryState:

```cs
 public class PageHistoryState
    {
        private List<string> previousPages;

        public PageHistoryState()
        {
            previousPages = new List<string>();
        }
        public void AddPageToHistory(string pageName)
        {
            previousPages.Add(pageName);
        }

        public string GetGoBackPage()
        {
            if (previousPages.Count > 1)
            {
                // You add a page on initialization, so you need to return the 2nd from the last
                return previousPages.ElementAt(previousPages.Count - 2);
            }

            // Can't go back because you didn't navigate enough
            return previousPages.FirstOrDefault();
        }

        public bool CanGoBack()
        {
            return previousPages.Count > 1;
        }
    }
```

Then add this class to the services as a singleton:

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<PageHistoryState>();
```

Inject it in your pages:

```
@inject WasmBlazor.Client.PageHistoryState PageHistoryState
```

In my markup then I've check to see if I can go back a page:

```js
@if (PageHistoryState.CanGoBack())
{
    <a href="@PageHistoryState.GetGoBackPage()">Go Back</a>
}
```

And I've overwritten `OnInitialized()`

```cs
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    PageHistoryState.AddPageToHistory("/counter");
    base.OnInitialized();
}
```

I've done the same thing in the "fetch data" page, and I'm able to go back without the need of the JSInterop.

Comment: In the GetGoBackPage method you probably want to remove the last page on the list - or you should provide some other method of decrementing the list when you go back a page. Otherwise you have no means of ever going back multiple pages, in which case you might as well use a couple of variables (currentPage, lastPage) instead of a list.

Comment: That's a good idea, I was thinking about a Queue, so you can Queue and Dequeue, what do you think?

Comment: Yes, something along those lines.

Comment: I think a Stack is what you want

Comment: As this is a singleton, I guess it will track the pages of all the users, right? So if multiple users use it you might go back to a page another user has visited before?

Comment: @Patric yeah, at the time it felt like a good idea, but know that I look at it, you might want to try a different approach such that, that doesn't happen

Comment: That won't happen since this service is registered on the client machine. The assumption here is that this is Blazor WASM.

Comment: just add it as Scoped in your startup\program class, then it will only live for single session

Answer (score 17):

I ended up with a bit improved solution that wraps/incapsulates the NavigationManager, keeps everything in a single place and does not depend on Pages or something else. It also keeps the history buffer size in some reasonable range.

**Navigation.cs**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing;

namespace MyApp
{
    public class Navigation : IDisposable
    {
        private const int MinHistorySize = 256;
        private const int AdditionalHistorySize = 64;
        private readonly NavigationManager _navigationManager;
        private readonly List<string> _history;

        public Navigation(NavigationManager navigationManager)
        {
            _navigationManager = navigationManager;
            _history = new List<string>(MinHistorySize + AdditionalHistorySize);
            _history.Add(_navigationManager.Uri);
            _navigationManager.LocationChanged += OnLocationChanged;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Navigates to the specified url.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="url">The destination url (relative or absolute).</param>
        public void NavigateTo(string url)
        {
            _navigationManager.NavigateTo(url);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns true if it is possible to navigate to the previous url.
        /// </summary>
        public bool CanNavigateBack => _history.Count >= 2;

        /// <summary>
        /// Navigates to the previous url if possible or does nothing if it is not.
        /// </summary>
        public void NavigateBack()
        {
            if (!CanNavigateBack) return;
            var backPageUrl = _history[^2];
            _history.RemoveRange(_history.Count - 2, 2);
            _navigationManager.NavigateTo(backPageUrl);
        }

        // .. All other navigation methods.

        private void OnLocationChanged(object sender, LocationChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            EnsureSize();
            _history.Add(e.Location);
        }

        private void EnsureSize()
        {
            if (_history.Count < MinHistorySize + AdditionalHistorySize) return;
            _history.RemoveRange(0, _history.Count - MinHistorySize);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _navigationManager.LocationChanged -= OnLocationChanged;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can add this class to dependency injection as a singleton service and initialise.

**Program.cs**

```cs
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace MyApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
            builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");

            builder.Services.AddSingleton<Navigation>();
            // .. other services.
            
            var host = builder.Build();
            await Initialize(host);
            await host.RunAsync();
        }

        private static async Task Initialize(WebAssemblyHost host)
        {
            host.Services.GetService<Navigation>();
            // .. other initialization calls.
        }
    }
}
```

After that you can use it in any place you want using the Inject directive/attribute.

**SomePage.cshtml**

```cs
@page "/SomePage"
@inject Navigation Navigation

<h3>SomePage</h3>

<button @onclick="NavigateBackClick">Navigate Back</button>

@code {
    private void NavigateBackClick()
    {
        Navigation.NavigateBack();
    }
}
```

**SomeService.cs**

```cs
namespace MyApp
{
    public class SomeService
    {
        private readonly Navigation _navigation;

        public SomeService(Navigation navigation)
        {
            _navigation = navigation;
        }

        public void SomeMethod()
        {
            // ...
            _navigation.NavigateBack();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why did you not simply use a stack?

Comment: `builder.Services.AddSingleton<Navigation>()` Are you sure, that for the server blazor such singleton be actual only for one user? (not for all users simultaneously)

Comment: @lealan, no. I did it only for client side. for server side it should be modified somehow... ;)

Comment: @JóhannØsterø there is removing from the "bottom of the stack" in EnsureSize() method

Comment: Deffinately dont use singleton, add it as scoped

Comment: Nice. I had to add a `forceload` boolean parameter to the `NavigateBack` method to be able to pass that on to the `NavigateTo` call inisde this method.

Answer (score 12):

I modified Diogo's answer above into what I feel is a much more elegant solution.

First, create a `BasePageComponent.cs` class, which inherits from the `ComponentBase` class:

```cs
// Using statements/namespace go here

[Authorize]
public class BasePageComponent: ComponentBase
{
    [Inject]
    protected NavigationManager _navManager { get; set; }
    [Inject]
    protected PageHistoryState _pageState { get; set; }

    public BasePageComponent(NavigationManager navManager, PageHistoryState pageState)
    {
        _navManager = navManager;
        _pageState = pageState;
    }

    public BasePageComponent()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();
        _pageState.AddPage(_navManager.Uri);
    }
}
```

This is what each of your pages will inherit from. It handles injecting the `PageHistoryState` service, as well as appending a newly navigated page. It does this all "behind the scenes" of your actual pages.

Now, in a given page, you inherit from `BasePageComponent`:

```cs
@page "/workouts/new"
@inherits BasePageComponent

/* ...RenderFragments/Razor view here...*/

@code {
    /* ...properties here...*/

    // This is an example of how to consume the _navManager and _pageState objects if desired, without any boilerplate code.
    private void OnCancel()
    {
        _navManager.NavigateTo(_pageState.PreviousPage());
    }
}
```

In my example component (stripped for brevity) it adds a new element to the page history stack with no markup besides inheriting from `BasePageComponent`.
Taylor

Comment: I have to put BasePageComponent in a namespace to work. I was having this error: error RZ3008: Tag helpers cannot target tag name '<global namespace>.BasePageComponent' because it contains a '<' character.

Answer (score 2):

This is an extension of [Diogo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62565035/4510954).

The correct implementation of `PageHistoryState` should use a Stack. Remember that you have to add some starting point to the history. You should call `AddPageToHistory` at your first page load (it could be MainLayout). If the history is empty, you will be redirected to the error page:

```cs
public class PageHistoryState
{
    private Stack<string> previousPages;
    private Stack<string> nextPages;
    private readonly string errorPageUrl;
    public PageHistoryState()
    {
        previousPages = new Stack<string>();
        nextPages = new Stack<string>();
        errorPageUrl = "/errorPage";
    }

    public void AddPageToHistory(string pageName)
    {
        previousPages.Push(pageName);
    }

    public string GetGoBackPage()
    {
        // This condition is to check if it is the first loaded page "/"
        if (previousPages.TryPeek(out string url) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url))
        {
            // If moved to the next page check
            if (previousPages.Count > 1)
            {
                // Pop the current page
                nextPages.Push(previousPages.Pop());
                // Pop the previous page -> "/"
                url = previousPages.Pop();
                return url;
            }
        }

        // If stack is empty redirect to the error page
        return errorPageUrl;
    }

    public string GetGoForwardPage()
    {
        if (nextPages.TryPop(out string url) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url))
            return url;

        // If stack is empty redirect to the error page
        return errorPageUrl;
    }

    public bool CanGoForward() => nextPages.Any();
    public bool CanGoBack() => previousPages.Count > 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Navigator Class

```cs
 public class Navigator
    {
        string _currentPage = "/";
        string _homePage { get; set; } = "/";
        NavigationManager Navigation { get; set; }
        IJSRuntime JS { get; set; }
        public void SetNavigation(NavigationManager navigation, IJSRuntime js, string dfaultPage = "/")
        {
            this.Navigation = navigation;
            this.JS = js;
            _currentPage = dfaultPage;
            _homePage = _currentPage;
        }
        public Navigator()
        {
            
        }
        public Stack<string> Navigators = new Stack<string>();
        public void NavigateTo(string parameter)
        {
            if (parameter != _currentPage)
            {
                Navigators.Push(parameter);
                Navigation?.NavigateTo(parameter);
                _currentPage = parameter;
            }
        }
        public async void ExecuteCommand(NavigateType code, string param)
        {
            if (code ==  NavigateType.Back)
            {
                if (Navigators.Count >= 1)
                {
                    string nav = null;
                    if(Peek() == param)
                        Navigators.Pop();
                    if(Navigators.Count >=1)
                      nav = Navigators.Pop();
                    if (nav != null)
                        _currentPage = nav;
                    else
                    {
                        _currentPage = _homePage;
                    }
                    await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("history.back");
                    BackPressed?.Invoke(this, nav);
                }
                else
                {
                   
                    _currentPage = _homePage;
                    await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("history.back");
                    BackPressed?.Invoke(this, null);
                   
                }
                
            }
            else if (code == NavigateType.Navigate)
            {
                if (param != _currentPage)
                {
                    _currentPage = param;
                    Navigators.Push(param);
                    Navigation?.NavigateTo(param);
                    Navigated?.Invoke(this, param);
                }

            }
        }
        public string Peek()
        {
            return Navigators.Peek();
        }
        public string Pop()
        {
            return Navigators.Pop();
        }
        public event EventHandler<string> BackPressed;
        public event EventHandler<string> Navigated;
    }
    public enum NavigateType
    {
        Navigate,
        Back,

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I created my own class which is registered as a service. Rather than use the client side to register a page change I used the MainLayout instead - so no JS required.

i inject the service into pages where I need a back button

i also added this to the MainLayout

```
<a href="@pvs.GetPreviousPage()">Go Back</a>






 @code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        pvs.AddPage(NavigationManager.Uri);

        NavigationManager.LocationChanged += LocationChanged;
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    void LocationChanged(object? sender, LocationChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is NavigationManager vm)
        {
            pvs.AddPage(NavigationManager.Uri);
        }
    }
}
```

public class PageVisitedService
{
List _pageVisitHistory = new List();

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a cloned list of history
    /// </summary>
    public List<string> PageVisitHistory
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<string>(_pageVisitHistory.Reverse<string>());
        }
    }


    public void AddPage(string page)
    {
        if (_pageVisitHistory.Count > 0 && page == _pageVisitHistory[_pageVisitHistory.Count - 1])
        {
            return;
        }

        _pageVisitHistory.Add(page);
    }

    public string GetPreviousPage()
    {
        if (_pageVisitHistory.Count > 0)
        {
            return _pageVisitHistory[_pageVisitHistory.Count - 1];
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```