# How to get the previous route in blazor?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

How do I get the previous route in blazor?
For example, we have many pages which required authentication. So when a user tries to access that page we navigate the user to the login page.
After success full login we want a user to redirect back to the page he requested.

Comment: You can see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62561926/blazor-navigation-manager-go-back) may helpful.

Comment: This is helpful but needs a better solution in build.